# function $g(t)$ as the maximum of the function $f(x)$ on a closed interval $[t,t+2]$

Tags: functions

For a function $$f(x)= x^2(x-3)$$, we want to define a function $g(t)$ as the maximum of the function $f(x)$ on a closed interval $[t,t+2]$.

I am trying to find it using a function called max, but it is difficult to express the maximum value in the interval. How can I do it?

Comment: Try `Maximize[]`.

Comment: `Maximize[{x^2(x-3), t<=x<=t+2},x] // First // Plot[#, {t, -4,4}]&`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

g[t_?NumericQ] := MaxValue[{x^2 (x - 3), t <= x <= t + 2}, x]

Plot[g[t], {t, -4, 4}, PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 4]
```

[image]